# instanceOf not working in application server

Tags: java

Below code work from my test case but if I run this in application server, `instanceOf` is not working and getting into else loop and throwing exception.

```
abstract class A { }

class B extends A { }

class C extends A { }

class MyClass {
    public void setObject(Object obj){  
        if(obj instanceOf A){
           //typecast
        }else
            throw new Exception("Object not supported");
        }
    }
```

Client Code-

```
B b = new B(); 
b.set..
MyClass client = new MyClass(); 
client.setObject(b);
```

Comment: u need to caste B as object i think.

Comment: u can not directly give Class as the reference Object i think u need to give object for checking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
abstract class A { }

class B extends A { }

class C extends A { }

class MyClass {

    public static void main(String args[]){
      //call method of the same calls
    }

public void setObject(Object obj){

 if(obj instanceof A){
   // assign your object
 }else
    throw new Exception("Object not supported");
}




}
```

Comment: I've corrected my question, same thing i'm doing in my actual code but running into issues

Answer (score 0):

Look this and shape your example according to this.

For example u need to check for the let say SecondClass which is extending first class.

```
abstract class FirstClass {

    public void setobject(Object o){
        if (o instanceof FirstClass) {
            System.out.println("Matched****");
        }else{
            System.out.println(" Not Matched****");
        }
    }

}

public class SecondClass extends FirstClass{

    public SecondClass() {
        System.out.println("Second Class*******");
    }

    @Override
    public void setobject(Object o) {
        super.setobject(o);
    }


}
```

and into your main calss check like this

```
SecondClass class1 = new SecondClass();
        if (class1 instanceof FirstClass) {
            System.out.println("Matched **************");
        }else{
            System.out.println("Not Matched **************");
        }
```